# chrome browser and selenium exception

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am receiving the following exception for my java code. All I want to do is open up a chrome browser. I have downloaded the proper chrome driver and stuck it in my google chrome folder under program files x86. Right now what happens is, the browser opens and then immediately says that the program has stopped working and then It throws the exception once I click exit on the window.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 23239
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main"   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new  session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'W7LPC01TDFU', ip: '10.95.7.58', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
```

here is my code so far

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mainTester {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    setUp();
}
public static void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
      // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
      Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
      WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
      searchBox.submit();
      Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
      System.out.println("Finished");
      driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what version of Chrome you are using? Chances are the latest since Google likes to autoupdate. You should be using the latest version of Chromedriver. The traceback you posted says you are using version 2.20 (`Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 23239`). The latest is 2.25 which Supports Chrome v53-55